# Javascript reduce with a nested array

Tags: javascript, nested, reduce

I'm trying to sum a nested array with the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method. My dat array looks like this:

```
var data = [
    [1389740400000, 576],
    [1389741300000, 608],
    [1389742200000, 624],
    [1389743100000, 672],
    [1389744000000, 691]
];
```

I got this:

```
// es5
data.reduce(function(prev, next) { return prev + next[1]; })

// es6 syntax
data.reduce((prev, next) => prev + next[1])
```

However I only do need the second value from each (nested) array. Any hints or tipps for me? I'm trying to sum all values within the array.

// Edit: Thanks for the answers. The problem was, that I missed the *initialValue* at the end.

```
// es6 solution
data.reduce((prev, next) => prev + next[1], 0)
```

Comment: I simple way to sum all values.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do it as following

```
var result = data.reduce(function (prev,next) {
    return prev + next[1];
},0);

console.log(result);//prints 3171
```

Here I am sending `0` as `prev` initially. So it will go like this

```
First Time  prev->0 next->[1389740400000, 576]
Second Time prev->576 next->[1389740400000, 608]
```

Do a `console.log(prev,next)` to understand much better.

If you'll see in docs you will get it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried different approaches, however I missed the last element. Maybe I should read the docs more carefully. :)

Answer (score 3):

A generic approach for all array, even if they are irregular styled.

Use: `array.reduce(sum, 0)`

```js
function sum(r, a) {
    return Array.isArray(a) ? a.reduce(sum, r) : r + a;
}

console.log([
    [1389740400000, 576],
    [1389741300000, 608],
    [1389742200000, 624],
    [1389743100000, 672],
    [1389744000000, 691]
].reduce(sum, 0));

console.log([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12, [13, 14, 15, 16]]
].reduce(sum, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have written would work if `data` is an array of integers. In your case, `data` is an array of arrays. Hence the return statement should operate on elements of the array:

```
return [previousValue[0] + currentValue[0], previousValue[1] + currentValue[1]];
```